# How to restore the exFAT structure on my hard disk?

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, android, filesystem-corruption

So I have a hard disk that contains a backup of some of my files (it has 2 partitions, a GUID partition map with one Time Machine “backup”, which is a clone of my Mac in APFS format, and other is a Backup of my historical data such as photos, archived work backup, etc. and pretty much anything that's "Archived" but this is in ExFAT format so I can see it on Windows or my TV too).

A friend visited and we wanted to watch a movie he has on his phone on my TV. I was going to connect the phone to my laptop to make the transfer when he said his phone (Vivo Iqoo 9) has OTG support and so I connected my hard disk to it directly. It showed a notification “preparing Sandisk…” and I got worried that it’s initializing it.

And so I pulled it out and connected it back to my laptop, and as I had suspected, the device has changed something and my data has disappeared. Instead, there are empty DCIM and USB folders in my "Archived" partition. Weirdly, the APFS backup partition is untouched and I'm able to see my time machine backup. I know there may be recovery tools like Recuva or DiskDrill that may do data recovery and get me the files in an unsorted manner but is there a simpler way to restore the hard disk to the ExFAT structure with my files?

Like... I imagine that when I originally initialized the hard disk's "Archived" partition as exFAT, it created a structure for the partition and I used it to store my data. And when I connected it to my friend's phone, it formatted it again. So can't I just restore that structure somehow to get access to my data again without having to use data recovery tools?

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: No, on mac. My hard disk was GUID partition mapped. I think that must have been why the Android phone triggered the initialization.

Comment: Unrelated, but a suggestion for the future: many devices and operating systems have or had the assumption that one UBS flash drive holds exactly one filesystem. Unless you strictly control what's accessing your drive, stick to that.

Comment: @SaifurRahmanMohsin use TestDisk, and follow the steps here up to "quick search" or "deeper search". If your partition is recoverable, you should see the ExFat partition and be able to list your missing files, and re-save the partition. Depending on how much was written (like DCIM), you may still lose some data. https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: Note for future: unless you really need it for cross-platform compatibility, don't use ExFAT on Mac. It's not journaled & can't hold unix permissions or extended attributes, so it can mess up some more complex Mac structures like Logic projects & Photos files. Use APFS for SSD & HFS+ for HD. [Time Machine will force APFS but you don't have to use it for other volumes]

Comment: I made it exFat specifically for cross-platform compatibility--I wanted that portion of my hard drive to work as a pen drive which I can use on my TV to watch stuff or even to store content across Windows/MacOS systems.

Comment: Fair point - though tbh, I'd be inclined to use disposable hardware for a disposable format like ExFAT. Use a cheap SD card/USB stick rather than 'solid' media. That way it's also never the only copy, so if it dies suddenly [as they do constantly] you can just bin it without a care.

Comment: You will need to be better job at describing previous partitions to what you have now. you mention you had exFAT, and you want it back to FAT32?

Comment: No, that is incorrect. I made an error. It was exfat before, and it appears to be exfat still. The android device merely initialised it when I connected my hard disk to it. I basically want to reverse the initialization and restore my files rather than the empty DCIM and USB folders which it created after initialisation. I have corrected the question now.

Comment: @SaifurRahmanMohsin, it then probably formatted the volume, can not be reversed. Recover files by copying to other drive using something like DMDE.

Comment: So I ended up using `dd` command to make a clone and then when I put that .img through Disk Drill, it gave me back the entire structure with all the old files AS-IS under a "Found Files - EXFAT" folder.